# Javascript error with typo3 extension and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3

I seem to have an issue with jQuery or javascript in general on my page with typo3. I want to use the extension "Easy route planner": http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/st_routeplanner

First jQuery of that extension was not working at all. I guess it was a conflict of the $ variable. This is why I replaced $ by jQuery in this file: http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/typo3conf/ext/st_routeplanner/static/st_routeplanner.js

Now the javascript runs ok until line 26 where this error is thrown:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/typo3conf/ext/st_routeplanner/static/st_routeplanner.js:26
```

The function in the code on that line is:

```js
jQuery('#st_routeplanner_submit').live('click',function(e){
    if(jQuery('#st_routeplanner_start').val()) {
    infowindow.close(map,marker);
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
});
```

I am not a javascript expert so I cannot make myself a clue out of this. What is going wrong?

If someone knows a better extension for a Google map with a route planner I am happy to try that one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery's `.live()` method has apparently been deprecated in **jQuery > 1.7** so the JavaScript code in the **st_routeplanner** extension is outdated.

I think your best option is to fix the code and replace `.live()` with `.on()`. See the **[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**.